# How to add image on right side while text is on the left. using div

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

basically i gave a div code which i got from bootsrap and i am tring to add the image within the div but it doesnt seem to fit in as well no matter how many times i change the image size by height and width.

as you see in the screenshot below the image falls off the border of the div. i want it contained neatly.  so text will be on the left and the image is on the left.

i have tried many time but failed. please someone help me i am uni student and trying to figure out all this alone but its taking alot of my time trying to fix it and its due in 6 days!!

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container my-5">
  <div class="row p-4 pb-0 pe-lg-0 pt-lg-5 align-items-center rounded-3 border shadow-lg">
    <div class="col-lg-7 p-3 p-lg-5 pt-lg-3">
      <h1 class="display-4 fw-bold lh-1">Welcome to the Neurodiverse Page!</h1>
      <p class="fs-5 mb-4">Here you will find many information to help be successful in a career in Ai or if your like many of just like learning more about Ai well this place is for you!</p>
      <p class="fs-5 mb-4">This website has been designed to have less clicks! meaning you can scroll through the information you need!</p>
      <p class="fs-5 mb-4">Dont forget to sign up which is at the bottom of this page!</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 offset-lg-1 p-0 position-relative overflow-hidden shadow-lg">
    <img class="d-block rounded-lg-3" src="bootstrap-docs.png" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
<div id="my_box">
  <div>
    <img src="https://miro.medium.com/max/1750/1*uQdZlvHn4rb4boX0_VBIVw.jpeg" width="895px" class="img-fluid.img-fluid. max-width: 100%; and height: auto;   alt=" "></div>
</div>
    </div>
```

[image: Help needed]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each of the column divs need to be in the row div to get what you want:

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container my-5">
    <div class="row p-4 pb-0 pe-lg-0 pt-lg-5 align-items-center rounded-3 border shadow-lg">
        <div class="col-lg-7 p-3 p-lg-5 pt-lg-3">
            <h1 class="display-4 fw-bold lh-1">Welcome to the Neurodiverse Page!</h1>
            <p class="fs-5 mb-4">Here you will find many information to help be successful in a career in Ai or if your like many of just like learning more about Ai well this place is for you!</p>
            <p class="fs-5 mb-4">This website has been designed to have less clicks! meaning you can scroll through the information you need!</p>
            <p class="fs-5 mb-4">Dont forget to sign up which is at the bottom of this page!</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 offset-lg-1 p-0 position-relative overflow-hidden shadow-lg">
            <img src="https://miro.medium.com/max/1750/1*uQdZlvHn4rb4boX0_VBIVw.jpeg" class="img-fluid" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```